# How to include by default icon inside a textarea

Tags: css, image, html, textarea

I was trying to insert a image inside a textarea but that seems to be impossible other than using `contenteditable ="true"` attribute of *textarea*. Meanwhile, I check [diaspora](https://joindiaspora.com/) site and I found that it can be possible. I ain't sure how that has been done. Is that really a *textarea* or *some css* trick via using div ? How can I implement the same?

Below image is a representation of that functionality:

[image]

Comment: If you inspect the element in your browser, you will probably find that the icon is simply absolutely positioned over the textarea. The tricky part will be how to implement that with a resizable textarea. In which case, you will probably need to use javascript to calculate the size of the textarea and apply those dimensions to a containing div element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use div that covers over the text area so that you can select image and submit form as multipart.
Its totally game of CSS.
You can use absolute div to position the button or image, all you need to do is to calculate the position w.r.t. the text area.
Check out this, the similar post at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314407/how-to-add-button-inside-input)

Comment: Does that mean, I need to check the browser window height and width for the same and at the same time i have to check the size of the textbox too ?

Comment: Check out this, the similar post at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314407/how-to-add-button-inside-input)

Comment: I got it how to figure it out! Thanks for the link :)

Comment: welcome 0to∞ :) 
you just have to figure how to style <input type="file"/>

Answer (score 3):

For things like this you are better off swapping out a textarea with an element to show a more complex display, using `.click()` and `.blur()` events. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/BumbleB2na/2XPcU/2/) that you can play around with.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <textarea class="text-area hidden"></textarea>
    <div class="text-area icon-example"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.text-area {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display:inline-block;
}

.icon-example:after {
    content: url(http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/dept-icons/camera-icon.gif);
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    right: 3px;
    bottom: 6px;
}

.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('.text-area').click(function() {
   $(this).hide();
   $(this).parent().find('textarea').show();
});
$('textarea').blur(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('div').text($(this).val()).show();
   $(this).hide();
});
```

You could take my example much further, playing around with CSS of the div and textarea so that their appearance eventually matches each other. I have done this before and it can be made to be cross-browser compatible.