# CSS focus on child element change a parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I want to style a form that has the label and input inside the form field and when I'll write something inside the input (probably with focus), I want the borders to light up with some blue. Now I have something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="login-form-field">
  <label for="email" class="login-form-label">Email:</label>
  <input class="login-form-input" autofocus="autofocus" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.login-form-input{
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
}
.login-form-label {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.login-form-field{
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 6rem;
  border: 0.5px solid grey;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

I already tried to select the parent to made some change and other stuff I found on google. The closest I got was to highlight with blue when the mouser was over it with :hover, but i need the color to stay as I'm with the input selected.

```
.login-form-field:hover {
  border-color: blue !important;
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7AaDc/219/), if anyone could help I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React with jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );

    $('.login-form-input').focus(function() {
         $(this).parent().css( "border", "#99f 2px solid" );
    });

    $('.login-form-input').focusout(function() {
         $(this).parent().css( "border", "" );
    });

});
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/7AaDc/220

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked and didn't messed up with the code at all, I thought I could do it in the css without making a mess haha

Answer (score 15):

You can now do this in pure CSS so no JavaScript is needed.

The new CSS pseudo-class `:focus-within` would help for cases like this and will help with accessibility when people use tabbing for navigating, common when using screen readers.

```
.login-form-field:focus-within {
  border-color: blue !important;
}
```

---

> The :focus-within pseudo-class matches elements that either themselves
>   match :focus or that have descendants which match :focus.

You can check which browsers support this http://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this, where you add an extra `div`, absolute positioned, which acts as the border, ... and no script is required.

```css
.login-form-input {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  outline: none;
}

.login-form-label {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.login-form-field {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 6rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
}
.login-form-field input ~ .login-form-field-border {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
  border: 0.5px solid grey;
  z-index: -1
}
.login-form-field input:focus ~ .login-form-field-border {
  border: 2px solid blue;  
}
```

```html
<div class="login-form-field">
  <label for="email" class="login-form-label">Email:</label>
  <input class="login-form-input" autofocus="autofocus" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email">
  <div class="login-form-field-border"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

CSS does not have native support for parent selecting.  If your goal is to have `.login-form-field` have a blue border on `focus` you're going to have to rely on JavaScript to add the respective CSS.

**The following CSS:**

```
.login-form-field.highlight {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

**With the following jQuery**

```
$('.login-form-field').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

Would achieve that goal.  I should note that jQuery is certainly not necessary here; it's just what I prefer to use.

Comment: @nicael Yes; for a more specific event I'd probably use something along the lines of `$('.login-form-input').focus(function() { $(this).parent().addClass('highlight'); }).blur(function() { $(this).parent().removeClass('highlight'); });` as that would trigger only on the exact `input` focus.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Although this is an old answer. I am answering this so anyone who lands here can use just CSS to achieve this.

Use CSS3 pseudo element: `focus-within`

You could do:

```
form:focus-within {
  border-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: There is no `focus-with`!!

Answer (score -3):

if you want to give the border color when the input is active you can add like this:

```
.login-form-input:focus {
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```