# How to add a button inside a input field

Tags: html, css

I have created a input field and a button but i want to put that button insiade that input field. I have done it by using `position:absolute` but the problem is its not working properly in medium or large screen. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Here is my code

HTML CODE

```
      <div>
          <div style="float: left;width: 82%">
                <input type="text" class="sent-message-text">

                <img src="../img/camera.png" class="post-image-uploaad">

          </div>
          <div style="float: right">
            <button class="no-button-design"><img src="../img/msg-sent.png" class="post-image-uploaad" style="margin-right: 15px;"></button>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.fixed-bottom2 {
box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 5px #ededed;
padding: 9px;
    margin:-20px !important
}
.sent-message-text {
border: 1px solid;
margin: 10px 0px 10px 15px;
min-height: 36px;
border: 1px solid #1486ab66 !important;
border-radius: 4px;
    width: 92%;
}

.post-image-uploaad {
    width: auto;
height: 22px;
margin-top: 8px;

}

.no-button-design {
    padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
background-color: transparent;
margin: 0px;

}

.no-button-design img {
    height: 34px;
}
```

In small screen its perfectly fine

[image]

But in large screen it's coming out from the input field

[image]

Comment: I've found a similar question maybe this will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314407/how-to-add-button-inside-input

Comment: Yes I've tried this but not working in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code

**css:-**

```
.fixed-bottom2 {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 5px #ededed;
    padding: 9px;
    margin: -20px !important
}

.sent-message-text {
        border: 1px solid;
margin: 10px 0px 10px 15px;
min-height: 36px;
border-radius: 4px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.post-image-uploaad {
  position: relative;
width: auto;
height: 22px;
margin: -39px -3px 1px 1px;
float: right;
}

.no-button-design {
       padding: 0px;
border: 0px;
background-color: transparent;
margin: 19px 35px;
}

.no-button-design img {
    height: 34px;
}
```

**html:-**

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left;width: 82%">
        <input type="text" class="sent-message-text">
        <img src="../img/camera.png" class="post-image-uploaad">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="no-button-design"><img src="../img/msg-sent.png" class="post-image-uploaad_send" style="margin-right: 15px;"></button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Bro It's working :) I will accept this answer after 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```css
form {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

form button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input name="search" type="text">
  <button type="submit">click</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

try this good luck

Answer (score 0):

### *Update in 2022*:for this question can try this code:

[image]

```css
.search {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  position: relative;
  width: 280px;
  height: 30px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  background-color: #e7c130;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div className='search'>
  <form>
    <input type='text' />
    <button>SEARCH</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text"/><button class="btn">button</button>
</body>
</html>
```