# Button CSS style in a search bar works fine on desktop but not on iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone

I was following another stack overflow post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314407/how-to-add-button-inside-input) to put a search button inside of a search bar using flex-grow property. It works fine on Desktop (both chrome and safari) 
[image: looks fine in desktop and mobile view of Chrome's developer tool]

It also looks fine in Mobile View of Chrome's developer tool, even mobile view of iPhoneSE:[image]

However, it looks different on iPhone (both chrome and safari) especially the search button.[image]

In addition, on iPhone SE, the search button is not inside of the search box. [image]

Here is my code (html):

```
    <div class='search'>
    <form class='search-form' method="POST" action="{% url 'search_forum_market' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input id='search-bar' name="searchterm" type="text">
    <input id='forum-button' type="submit" value="Search" name="_forum">

    </form>
    </div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.search {
grid-column: 2;
width: 500px; 
max-width: 100%;
justify-self: center;
}

.search-form {
/* This bit sets up the horizontal layout */
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
/* This bit draws the box around it */
border:2px solid grey;
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px; 
width: 100%; 
max-width: 500px; /* added */
margin: 8px 0; /* added */
}

#search-bar {
/* Tell the input to use all the available space */
flex-grow:2;
/* And hide the input's outline, so the form looks like the outline */
border: white 1px;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 4px; 
border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px; 
}

#forum-button{
background: gray;
color: black;
font-size: 16px;
border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px; 
border: gray solid 1px; 
padding: 2px; 
}
```

I could not figure out why this is happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To Fix the issues you have all you need to do is to use Media Query to resolve the issues for iPhone and iPad:

**for iPad**: use

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
{/*STYLES GO HERE */ 
.search {/*write css to fix*/} 
.search-form {/* This bit sets up the horizontal layout */}
}
```

You have to rewrite your CSS codes to fit the screen size.

**for iPhone portrait and landscape**: Use

```css
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. My real problem is the style of button has changed. I edited my question and added two more pictures: one is mobile view of chrome's developer tools and another one from iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

i think there are some CSS affect on your form css because i try this this css and html it's works fine for all devices

Comment: oh really? was the button style the same? Thanks!